# Change Product Quantity Without Edit on Magento

Tags: product, admin, quantity

**I have a question here, how to change product stock without click "Edit" on Magento ?**
[image: Here]

**Thanks Before**

Answer (score 2):

There are third party modules for that.

Take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=grid+edit&pl=0